# Conda and Anaconda both on Windows machine. Jupyter notebook cannot import Python packages

Tags: python, windows-7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

The goal is I'm trying to use autograd in Jupyter Notebook on my Windows 7 machine.

Here is what I have done:

- I activated a conda environment, in git bash, using `source activate myenv`
- I installed autograd using `conda install -c omnia autograd`
- I started Jupyter notebook with `jupyter notebook`

Now when I try to import autograd in Jupyter notebook, I have the following error:

```
No module named 'autograd'
```

So I stopped the Jupyter notebook and tried to use `pip` to install again. But I have this error:

```
$ pip install autograd
Requirement already satisfied: autograd in c:\users\******\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9 in c:\users\******\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages (from autograd) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\******\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages (from autograd) (0.16.0)
```

Apparently, conda thinks it already installs autograd.

So I thought I might have two versions of conda installed? Here are the results of my `conda env list`:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
myenv                 *  C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv
```

And in both conda installations there is a 'pkg' folder, with different packages installed.

My speculation is Jupyter notebook is connected to the 'base' anaconda3, which does not have autograd installed?

My question is simply how can I use autograd in Jupyter notebook, and possibly clean everything up so I do not have two condas installed on my machine?

Here are the results for activate myenv and run `conda list`:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv:
#
_py-xgboost-mutex         2.0                       cpu_0  
autograd                  1.1.2               np112py36_0    omnia
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                     <pip>
Cython                    0.28.4                    <pip>
django                    2.0.5            py36hd476221_0    anaconda
future                    0.16.0                   py36_1  
icc_rt                    2017.0.4             h97af966_0  
idna                      2.7                       <pip>
intel-openmp              2018.0.3                      0  
kaggle                    1.3.12                    <pip>
libxgboost                0.72                          0  
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6  
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7  
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7  
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2  
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2  
mkl                       2018.0.3                      1  
mkl_fft                   1.0.1            py36h452e1ab_0  
mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h9258bd6_0  
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1  
numpy                     1.12.1           py36hf30b8aa_1  
numpy-base                1.14.5           py36h5c71026_0  
pandas                    0.23.1           py36h830ac7b_0  
pip                       10.0.1                   py36_0  
py-xgboost                0.72             py36h6538335_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.23                    <pip>
python                    3.6.5                h0c2934d_0  
python-dateutil           2.7.3                    py36_0  
pytz                      2018.4                   py36_0    anaconda
requests                  2.19.1                    <pip>
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36h53aea1b_0  
scipy                     1.1.0            py36h672f292_0  
setuptools                39.2.0                   py36_0  
six                       1.11.0           py36h4db2310_1  
tqdm                      4.23.4                    <pip>
urllib3                   1.22                      <pip>
vc                        14                   h0510ff6_3  
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    3  
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0  
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0  
xgboost                   0.72                      <pip>
```

Comment: Can you show the result if you activate myenv then run `conda list`? This shows all packages that conda can find in that environment.

Comment: @SNygard added. Thanks!

Comment: You need to install `jupyter notebook` into this environment as well

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can check. First, guarantee that your package exists inside the environment by running:

```
> source activate myenv
(myenv) > conda list
```

There will be a list of packages that conda can find for that environment. Make sure you see `autograd` there!

---

Next, in your Jupyter notebook, run the following:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

This shows the full path of the python executable running the notebook. You should see something similar to: `~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python`. If you don't see `myenv` in the path, then Jupyter is running in a different environment. It's likely that your system path finds a different Jupyter first. Check your environment variables to see if another Jupyter comes first.

You can force Jupyter to run from a specific environment by starting it with the full path: `~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/juypter`

Comment: Just revisiting this answer and I finally understood how packages and environments works in Python. Thanks for writing the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exclamation bang in an iPython cell, to install `autograd` as such:

`!pip install autograd`.

This way the installation is guaranteed to correspond to the iPython kernel.

Comment: thanks. Tried and still get the 'Requirement already satisfied' error....